# "Undefined" error response from AJAX JQUERY call to XML file

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am doing a prototype that will fetch a variety of XMLs from a web resource location and then display them on the DOM.

Here is the function

```
    function readXML()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://collaboratewiki.com/wikiattachments/61736956/engineer.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) 
        {
            window.alert("success")
        },
        error: function(xhr,err)
        {
            alert("readyState: "+err.readyState+"\nstatus: "+err.status);
            alert("responseText: "+err.responseText);
        }
});


}
```

When I call this function it goes to the error case but I get "Undefined" in my message output.

[image]

I need to find out why I can't fetch my XML but with this output its not helpful at all.

How do I get all the details of the error that is happening with the AJAX call?

I have tried instead of "err.responseText" , "xhr.responseText" but I still get the undefined.

Thanks

Comment: P.s. could it be because its HTTPS?

Comment: Are you getting any other errors from the console?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> error
>
> Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )

The second and third arguments are strings, not objects, so they won't have additional properties on them. Some of the ones you're trying to get (such as `readyState`) will be available from the `xhr` object in your code, rather than from `err` (which is just a string).

You may want to try something like this:

```
error: function(xhr,textStatus,err)
{
    console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
    console.log("responseText: "+ xhr.responseText);
    console.log("status: " + xhr.status);
    console.log("text status: " + textStatus);
    console.log("error: " + err);
}
```

Comment: I dont really understand the Jquery documentation , it does not make sense to me. Could you give me code solution please.

Comment: @loosebruce Updated with a code snippet (I can't guarantee those properties are available, but I believe they are). You really should learn how to understand the documentation, though, it will answer most questions for you; the key part here is the *types* of the arguments passed - you were trying to use strings as objects.

Comment: Ok I just tried this , the output was : readystate = 0 , responsetext ="" , status = 0 , textstatus = "error" m error = "".

What does this mean?

Comment: @loosebruce You may be running up against the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Ok I just tried putting the XML on another resource location and I now get an error : "No Transport"

Comment: Ok I just tried using "jQuery.support.cors = true;" , it now works in IE9 but not FF

Comment: @Anthony Grist - This was awesome and helped me get the xhr.responseText so I could troubleshoot my issue!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
                $("#box #tozihat .x1").click(
                function()
                {
                    var id=0
                    var length='';
                    id=$(this).attr('id');
                    length=$("#bordersabad #"+id+"").length;



                    $.ajax({
                        type:'post',
                        url:"sabad.php",
                        data:{idmahsool:id}
                        })
                        .done(function(){

                            if(length==1){
                                var tedad=0;
                                tedad=$("#bordersabad #"+id+"#tedad").html();
                                alert(tedad);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            }

                        })

                })
```